# native scrolling not working on ionic

Tags: scroll, ionic-framework

I am trying to use native scrolling like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp').config(function ($translateProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'languages/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
    if(!ionic.Platform.isIOS())$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
})
```

the issue that my scrolling stop working at all very similar to: [code pen](http://codepen.io/felquis/pen/aOyYEZ)

my template:

```
 <div class="list">
        <a ng-repeat="item in items" class="item card"
           href="#/tab/details/{{item.queId}}">
                <div class="row">....
```

thanks For helping!

after looking on it looks that the issue happens only on chrome....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native scrolling only works on Android platforms.

You can read more about it in one of the recent blog posts [here](http://blog.ionic.io/native-scrolling-in-ionic-a-tale-in-rhyme/) and in the forum [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-scrolling-android-testers-wanted/17059).

The syntax you're using is ok:

```
if (!ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
  }
```

but you can only test it on an android device.

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen scrolls fine without this line:

```
if(!ionic.Platform.isIOS())$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
```

Why are you disabling the scroll in non iOS platforms with this code?